# strange performance behavior when running app from scripting language

Tags: performance, scripting, operating-system, tcl

I wrote tcl script as an glue between different apps which are computationally intensive.
When I run `top` command I see that 2 cpu's are 100% utilized.
The one is for the tcl and the second is for the application I am running.
**The question is: why the tcl is utilizing fully one of the processors** when the binary application is heavily computationally?

Thx.

Comment: What is the tcl script doing, other than waiting for the other program to quit?

Comment: Need more info! Could you possibly paste the TCL that executes while the app is running? How did you actually start it up?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for such late response. Actually I am using interface which was provided by company for this computationally intensive tasks. I can't track any details how the tcl is launching this tools in background because the API is provided as an shared library (compiled in c) and I do not have sources. The thing is that I can run these external tools from command line. I know they are resource hungry. However I thought that in such case the tcl process itself should be idle. The tcl script does not process or controls this tools in anyway. Once they are launched they generate results.

Comment: It sounds like the tcl script itself should be idle, as you state. That being said, it's likely either there is something happening that you're not aware of... or someone made a mistake in the code that's causing the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were guessing I'd say the TCL script is polling something; returned messages perhaps?  The 'right' way is to use interrupts, but that's always a fun TCL exercise.  On the other hand there's a possibility the TCL isn't the problem at all - if you can get at the TCL source, put "after 1000000" or the like after the tool call; then you'll know if it's really the TCL you have, or something else masked by the DLL.

If there's no good way to edit the vendor TCL then perhaps you can use TCL on a 'slow' remote machine, and call the application itself on the 'fast' machine using SSH or telnet.

Comment: thx for the answer, the tcl is waiting for the results and that was the issue. thx one more time.

Answer (score 0):

More specifics would be helpful: which tools are you speaking about?  For what purpose do they provide a Tcl interface?  Did you create the Tcl script?  How do you invoke it?